# How to handle 404 return code (by design) in int-http:outbound-gateway?

Tags: rest, spring-integration, spring-integration-http

I code a Spring Integration route that queries a SOAP and a REST WS and somehow aggregates the results. I use a bean as payload to gather the useful information along the way, two payload enrichers to query the web services and a transformer at the end to build the result.

Now my problem is that the REST WS returns (by design) HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND (404) if the system has no information about the entity I'm querying. That needs be considered a nominal use case. Spring Integration considers this by default an error and bails out. I need to handle this case properly, store null in my bean or something similar (I can handle that down the road) and proceed.

So I've tried adding an error-handler to the outbound-gateway but could not make this work. If I tell this is not an error (overriding hasError()) then SI tries to unmarshall the body of the response, which obviously does not work; same if I override handleError() and do nothing.

Maybe I'm not going in the right direction but I miss a better idea so... any help accepted with gratitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add for the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` a `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` as a nested `<request-handler-advice-chain>` and use its options: `onFailureExpression`, `returnFailureExpressionResult = true`. You may also consider to use `failureChannel`.

This way you catch that `404 NOT FOUND` exception and return whatever you think is appropriate compensation result.

More information you can find in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain) and there is also a [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more) project on the matter.

Comment: Thank you! It took me a couple of days to figure out the exact settings but that was definitely the way to go. Happy to see the documentation exists even if it is not where I expected ;-) The two pointers to documentation and example have been especially useful (and much appreciated).

Comment: @Her-Bak While it's been quite a while since this was posted, if you're able to update this Answer or your Question with the 'exact settings' it would be quite helpful for the Spring Integration knowledge base.